# Merging files that are formatted differently in Rstudio

Tags: r, csv, merge, format

For my master thesis I'm trying to merge two files, they contain the following:
one has metrics on my study subjects (seagulls), the other has the reproductive success of these birds.

They are, however, formatted differently: the file with metrics already takes two separate rows for the different phases of the breeding period, thus an individual has multiple rows per year.

The other file with reproductive success does not, there is only one row per individual per year, and the columns belonging to these rows represent the reproductive parameters of each breeding phase.

Now I know I can't just straight up 'merge' the two files in Rstudio, so I wonder how I would go about formatting the files so I can.

I will add pictures to help with interpretation:
 [First file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mV41v.png)
 [Second file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfYNi.png)

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: much better to provide some data than as a picture. `dput` can help.  Also please add the code you have so far.

Comment: Hello Richard, thanks for your reply, the thing is that I'm just looking for a way to format these two csv files (in Rstudio if possible), so there is no code thus far, just the two files that I don't know how to merge together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should first start by considering WHY you want to merge the files. From what I can see, your files are best kept separate, because in your first file, you are recording common metrics across both phases (headers are the same), while in the second first, you are recording differing metrics across both phases (headers are different).

As the second file contains differing headers for the 2 phases, it would not be possible to convert it to a similar form of the first file. It is however possible to convert the first file into the format of the second file, and hence allowing you to combine the two files. However I strongly caution against this, as it could prevent you from making quick analysis of your data in this manner.

```
library(ggplot2)
dat <- read.csv("file1.csv")
# This plots a boxplot comparing the evenness of the 2 phases
ggplot(dat, aes(x = as.factor(period), y = evenness)) + geom_boxplot()
```

[image: Boxplot sample]

However if you insist, here is the code to reformat file1 into a single row per entry to be combined with file2

```
# One more warning, depending on how you 
# want to eventually wrangle your data, 
# doing this might make your life more difficult

library(dplyr)
f1 <- read.csv("file1.csv", stringAsFactors = FALSE)
dat1 <- dat[f1$phase == "incubating",]
dat2 <- dat[f1$phase == "chickrearing",]
dat2$phase <- dat1$phase <- NULL
names(dat1) <- c("bird.year", paste0("incubating.", names(dat1)[2:length(names(dat1))]))
names(dat2) <- c("bird.year", paste0("chickrearing.", names(dat2)[2:length(names(dat2))]))

f1.combined <- merge(dat1, dat2, by = "bird.year")

f2 <- read.csv("file2.csv")
f2 <- mutate(f2, bird.year = paste(Individual, year))

combined.files <- merge(f1.combined, f2, by = "bird.year")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply!
The reason I want to merge them, is because I want to see how the metrics (that are already formatted per phase), relate to the reproductive performance of the individuals behind those metrics (but the reproductive performances are on one row per individual in a given year, instead of split into phases like the metrics).

I will update this if the solution works! :)